# What's the difference between DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT and DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I implement the following class:

```
class GCDStudy {

    func asyncSerial(time:Double){
        let queue = dispatch_queue_create("DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL",DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

        dispatch_async(queue){

            var i:Double = 0
            while(i < 3){
                i++
                print("asyncSerial -wait:\(time)-\(i)")

            }
        }

    }

    func asyncConcurrent(time:Double){

        let queue = dispatch_queue_create("DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT",DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)

        dispatch_async(queue){
            var i:Double = 0
            while(i < 3){
                i++
                print("asyncConcurrent -wait:\(time)-\(i)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And run as the following:

Run A:

```
gCDStudy = GCDStudy()
gCDStudy.asyncSerial(1)
gCDStudy.asyncSerial(2)
```

Run B

```
vgCDStudy2 = GCDStudy()
gCDStudy2.asyncConcurrent(1)
gCDStudy2.asyncConcurrent(2)
```

And the result RunA:

```
asyncSerial -wait:1.0-1.0
asyncSerial -wait:2.0-1.0
asyncSerial -wait:1.0-2.0
asyncSerial -wait:2.0-2.0
asyncSerial -wait:1.0-3.0
asyncSerial -wait:2.0-3.0
```

The result of RunB:

```
asyncSerial -wait:1.0-1.0
asyncSerial -wait:2.0-1.0
asyncSerial -wait:1.0-2.0
asyncSerial -wait:2.0-2.0
asyncSerial -wait:1.0-3.0
asyncSerial -wait:2.0-3.0
```

These results are the same, what is the different between these?

Sometimes these results are different.

Thanks

Comment: You only dispatch one block to the queue in each example. To see the difference, dispatch multiple blocks to each queue. In other words, put the call to `dispatch_async` inside a loop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Serial queues execute one task at a time in the order in which they are added to the queue whereas concurrent queues execute one or more tasks concurrently. An important thing to note is that, even for *concurrent queues*, tasks are started in the order in which they were added to the queue. Because of that, in your case, you'll probably see no change in the output  as `print` will be executed pretty fast by each thread in the concurrent queue so that it'll seem as if they were executed sequentially.

If you expect to see a difference, maybe you might try updating your code as follows:

```
class GCDStudy {

  func asyncSerial(time: Double) {
    let queue = dispatch_queue_create("DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

    for i in 0..<3 {
      dispatch_async(queue) {
        print("asyncSerial -wait:\(time)-\(i)")
      }
    }
  }

  func asyncConcurrent(time: Double) {
    let queue = dispatch_queue_create("DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)

    for i in 0..<3 {
      dispatch_async(queue) {
        print("asyncConcurrent -wait:\(time)-\(i)")
      }
    }
  }
}
```